# Y axis numbers change when zoom in and out

Tags: graphite, statsd

I deployed graphite with statsd on ubuntu 14.04 and then pump some incremental numbers to that.
What I see is when I zoom in like last 24 minutes, it shows 1000 on y axis which is coorrect. Then when I zoom out to 24 hour, that number goes down to 500.
I tried several test data generation and I see same behavior;[image: 24 hours] [image: 24 mins]

It shows the correct numbers for 2 hours perpective.
[image]
I would appreciate if anyone can shed some lights to this.
Storage-schema.conf;

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[stats]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 10s:6h,1min:7d,10min:5y
```

storage-aggregation.conf

```
[min]
pattern = \.lower$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[max]
pattern = \.upper$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[sum]
pattern = \.sum$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[count]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[count_legacy]
pattern = ^stats_counts.*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[default_average]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.3
aggregationMethod = average
```

Comment: Could you paste your `storage-schemas.conf` and `storage-aggregation.conf`? It is mostly likely due to retention.

Comment: Just updated the question for the conf files.
Funny thing is that the numbers fluctuates big time 
0 -2 hour it shows 1000 counts 
3-6 hours 500 counts 
7-17 hours back to 1000 counts again 
18 hours to 1 day 500 counts
after this it keeps going down ...
No clue what is happening here

Comment: Your config looks fine. Have you updated it recently? Changes in aggregation only affect new metrics: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf "Changing this file will not affect .wsp files already created on disk. Use whisper-set-aggregation-method.py to change those".  Try using a metric with a new name.

Answer (score 0):

Statsd writes to a fixed size database (whisper) which means that it only stores a fixed amount of data per metric. In order to do that it aggregates multiple points into one value (called rollup aggregation) after a certain amount of time (specified by your retention schema).

Looks like you have the following schema for stats:

```
[stats]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 10s:6h,1min:7d,10min:5y
```

Which means it'll store data points at a 10 seconds resolution for 6 hours, after 6 hours it'll store data at a 1 minute resolution for 7 days. How those points are aggregated are specified by aggregationMethod.